# Is gl_VertexID available in an OpenGL ES 2.0 Extension?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, ios9.3

Is gl_VertexID available in an extension to OpenGL ES 2.0? As a further question, is that extension available on iOS? On iPad 2?

Comment: I looked for a bit, and couldn't find one. As far as I can tell, you need ES 3.0

Comment: @RetoKoradi, Thanks, me too.